# If my model class imports HttpServletRequest, Datanucleus enhancer throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Is there a Datanucleus setting to prevent the enhancer throwing an error if the HttpServletRequest class is imported by the model class that is being enhanced?

```
Aug 11, 2011 11:06:34 PM org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.JdoClassAdapter visitEnd
WARNING: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(Unknown Source)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.JdoClassAdapter.visitEnd(JdoClassAdapter.java:338)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer.enhance(ASMClassEnhancer.java:355)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhanceClass(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:974)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:570)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict which classes are being enhanced, so just enhance the persistable ones. If you don't it will have to search for annotations and by doing that will need to load the class definition, and Java's class loader will complain if you don't have your dependencies in your classpath